# Analyzing the incoming requests data in Ubuntu

Tags: networking

I'm trying to reverse engineer some utility in Ubuntu. On Mac, I use Charles proxy to debug the network, and I'm looking for a similar solution on Ubuntu. The Ubuntu machine is an online server and hosting a LAMP stack. Based on my research, tcpdump and other utilities are there but I'm not able to analyze the data using those utilities. Charles proxy on Mac provides a readable form of the data but I believe the tools I tried in Ubuntu capture packets, I'm not sure.

My question is, how to log the network requests in a readable form and to analyze the request parameters (headers, form values, and so on)? One of my thoughts is to redirect all incoming requests to an external webhook so I'll be able to analyze the posted data. Is this possible? Looking forward to the best solution. I'd like to mention again that the server doesn't offer a GUI and it is hosting a LAMP stack.

**Edit:** I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.x without any GUI.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

You could try,

**[slurm](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/slurm)** - colored interface

[image of slurm as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xINK4.png)

**[bmon](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/net/bmon)** - view multiple interfaces at once

[Image of bmon as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqOh6.png)